# Connect to different firebase types

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve data from two different firebase firestores (web and flutter) and show them in different places in my app so I'm wondering if I could do it due to web firebase has been made for a separate web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you can use two different instances of a Firestore Database, as explained in the [`cloud_firestore` package documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore-class.html):

> You can get an instance by calling FirebaseFirestore.instance. The
> instance can also be created with a secondary Firebase app by calling
> `FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor`.

```
FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app('SecondaryApp');
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp);
```